# Displaying query results in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So in my model a user has many roles through assignments and a role can have many users through assignments. I've managed to get the function for creating new assignments up and running but I want to display all the roles a user can perform on the user index page (which lists all the users).

My code for the users stub view thus far is:

```
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.phone %></td>
    <td><%= user.roles.select("description")%></td>
```

The problem here is that instead of displaying the description for the role the output is:

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the relation into an array of the strings, so that:

```
<td><%= user.roles.select("description")%></td>
```

becomes:

```
<td><%= user.roles.select("description").map &:description %></td>
```

or:

```
<td><%= user.roles.select("description").map(&:description).join(", ") %></td>
```

to join it into a single comma-separated string.

Comment: That works but is there any way of displaying the data without the array tags? The current output looks like: ["Guitarist"]

Comment: user.roles.select("description").map(&:description).join(", ")

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
user.roles.select("description").map(&:description).join(", ")
```